# Android users asking for validation code?

Tags: android, validation, mobile, device, administrator

I do support for an android app which uses device admin rights and people are asking me for a validation code. Does anyone know what the exact name for this code is and where I can point them? This issue seemed to arise starting November 2023.

I thought this maybe an extra layer of security for the device admin rights, but I cant find any setting on my Samsung phone.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of that message.

Comment: I asked for one but havent received any so far. Apparently it just says "Verification Code" once they try to add the app to the device administrator list.